# ¿Qué son las Clases? ¿Se pueden crear muchas?

Tags: java, android, clase

Tengo  una pregunta al crear una clase:

```
ej = new Ejemplo("1");
```

Me gustaría saber a qué equivale una clase. Siempre quise crear muchas clases para una mejor identificación.

He leído que cuando alguien deja muchos objetos en un HashMap causa lag, y creo que una clase pesa mucho más que un simple Objecto.

Si yo creo muchas clases por ejemplo 200 clases, ¿esto causaría retrasos? Y también ¿es necesario borrarlas?

Yo estoy haciendo un juego, cuando el jugador agarra la moneda esa moneda desaparece, pero esa moneda es una class, cuando la moneda desaparece la class ya se vuelve inútil pero sigue estando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes una confusión entre **clase** y **objeto**. Trataré de explicarte la relación y la diferencia entre estas.

En sentido estricto, en tiempo de ejecución de un programa no puedes *crear* una clase. Lo único que puedes crear en la memoria son objetos.

Por supuesto que hay una relación entre clase y objeto. Veamos primero la definición que se encuentra en [Conceptos de objetos y clases en Java](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=411:conceptos-de-objetos-y-clases-en-java-definicion-de-instancia-ejemplos-basicos-y-practicos-cu00619b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188)

> **Objeto**: entidad existente en la memoria del ordenador que tiene unas propiedades (atributos o datos sobre sí mismo almacenados por el objeto) y unas operaciones disponibles específicas (métodos).
>
> **Clase**: abstracción que define un tipo de objeto especificando qué propiedades (atributos) y operaciones disponibles va a tener.

Sé que esto es algo confuso al inicio y la mejor analogía que sé, es la de molde-objeto.

Imagina un objeto de la vida real, que tiene una forma determinada, por ejemplo una figura de plástico.

La **clase** es el *molde* con el que puedes fabricar cada **instancia** de la figura. Cada instancia tendrá sus propios atributos, por ejemplo su color.

Volviendo al inicio, en tiempo de ejecución no puedes crear *clases*. Lo que haces es crear *instancias de objetos*, utilizando para ello el constructor de su clase, que es la manera en que cada uno se *fabrica*. Lo que ocupa memoria en el computador, son estas instancias de objetos.

Si 200 instancias de un objeto particular son muchas o pocas dependerá de la cantidad de memoria disponible para tu proceso en el dispositivo donde se ejecuta y de la cantidad de memoria que cada instancia ocupe. Además de la memoria, las instancias de objetos creadas pueden consumir otros recursos.

Hablando de java en particular, no es necesario que liberes manualmente la memoria, pero si debes ser cuidadoso de no mantener referencias a objetos que ya no necesitas, para minimizar el consumo innecesario de memoria y otros recursos. El [recolector de basura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recolector_de_basura) de la JVM se encargará de liberar la memoria de todos aquellos objetos que han salido de ámbito. Tu puedes influenciar que un objeto sea liberado, incluso antes de salir del ámbito donde fue creado eliminando la referencia al mismo. Por ejemplo, si tienes una rutina como esta:

```
{
  MiClase miObjeto = new MiClase();
  miObjeto.HacerAlgo();
  TrabajarCon(miObjeto);
  //a partir de este punto miObjeto ya no se utiliza, pero la rutina sigue
  HacerOtrasCosas(conOtrosObjetos);
  YOtras();
  YMuchasMas();
}
//la instancia de miObjeto no será liberada sino hasta después 
//de este punto, que es cuando la variable miObjeto sale de contexto.
```

Puedes influenciar al GC a que destruya el objeto antes realizando este cambio:

```
{
  MiClase miObjeto = new MiClase();
  miObjeto.HacerAlgo();
  TrabajarCon(miObjeto);
  //a partir de este punto miObjeto ya no se utiliza, pero la rutina sigue
  //elimino la referencia
  miObjeto = null; 
  HacerOtrasCosas(conOtrosObjetos);
  YOtras();
  YMuchasMas();
}
```

Cuando digo *puedes influenciar* me refiero a que no tienes una garantía del momento en que la instancia del objeto será destruida. Eso lo *decide* la JVM y puede variar entre versiones de esta, sistema operativo, etc.

Si es imperativo que se liberen recursos a partir de cierto punto en tu programa, es mejor que realices la implementación de dicha liberación en un método que tu mismo invoques, por ejemplo:

```
{
  MiClase miObjeto = new MiClase();
  miObjeto.hacerAlgo();
  trabajarCon(miObjeto);
  //a partir de este punto miObjeto ya no se utiliza, pero la rutina sigue
  //libero recursos y elimino la referencia
  miObjeto.cerrarSocket();
  miObjeto.cerrarArchivos();
  miObjeto.liberarStreams();
  miObjeto.liberarMemoriaAdicional();
  miObjeto = null; 
  //continúo con mi vida, solo dios y la JVM saben cuando se va a 
  //liberar realmente miObjeto
  hacerOtrasCosas(conOtrosObjetos);
  yOtras();
  yMuchasMas();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Para definir una clase es importante definir un Objeto, que es una entidad que contiene propiedades (atributos) y comportamiento (métodos).
Una Clase es definida por un tipo de objeto.

Puedes crear muchas clases las cuales cada instancia ocupa memoria pero debes recordar que los recursos en los dispositivos moviles son limitados, si llenas de objetos en algun momento obtendras un error [OutofMemory](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html), el cual es muy común cuando no realizas un optimo manejo de la memoria, primeramente experimentaras que tu aplicación se vuelve lenta (lag) y posteriormente puede causar que tu aplicación se cierre.

Error  [OutofMemory](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) :  es causado cuando la maquina virtual de Java no puede alojar un objeto porque no se tiene memoria, y no puede haber más memoria disponible por el Garbage Collector.

El trabajo que realiza el Garbage Collector es eliminar los objetos que no tienen referencia en el stack.

Si tienes objetos que son "inutiles pero continuan en memoria", elimina su referencia para que el Garbage Collector actue y libere memoria que podría requerir tu aplicación.

He leido varios articulos donde comentan que se debe llamar el Garbage Collector para liberar memoria.

```
System.gc();
```

Actualmente no es algo que asegura liberar memoria ya que al realizar esto no asegura los objetos sean recolectados (no trates de ser más inteligente que el sistema operativo).

El caso mas simple para eliminar el objeto de memoria es simplemente asignando el valor null:

```
//creación de objeto.
    MiClase miInstancia = new MiClase();
....
//En este punto decido no mantener este objeto.
miInstancia = null;
```

También puedes implementar el método [finalize()](https://datafull.co/p/cuando-se-llama-al-metodo-finalize-en-java).

Esta es la documentación oficial relacionada al manejo de memoria en Android (inglés):

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: Muy buena respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, esto es un tema algo extenso pero espero haber contestado de una forma básica lo que pregunta el OP, saludos!.